# How to retrieve the active tab, inside message listener in background, in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the following code (in *background.js*) to get the active tab

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log("active tab retrieved : " + tabs[0].id);
});
```

This works great, except for one case: when this piece of code is inside a messaging listener. For example the next scenario:

*In background.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) { 
        console.log("message received");
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            console.log("active tab retrieved : " + tabs[0].id);
        });
    }
);
```

*in content_script.js*

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({}, function(response) {});
```

I only got the following in console

> message received

and I didn't get the second log in console.

**Why is this happening and how to solve it ?**

Comment: Just qurious: Are you trying to get the active tab or the tab that sent the message ?

Comment: I think that both are the same, but to be more accurate I want to get the tab which sent the message

Comment: I got your point of using sender.tab , but why the code above doesn't work ?

Comment: See my answer below. After adding the missing `);` the code seems to work fine for me :)

Comment: It was a wrong copy of my original code. I'll give sender.tab a try. PS, initial post edited with parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unclosed parenthesis in your code, which raises an exception and aborts execution. Correct it like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) { 
        console.log("message received");
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            console.log("active tab retrieved : " + tabs[0].id);
        });   // <-- add `);`
    }
);
```

That said, if you just want to get the tab that sent the message, it is much easier:

```
sender.tab.id
```

Comment: I copied it wrong to stackoverflow, it's with ');' but doesn't work,
I'll give sender.tab a try and ping you back.

Comment: It is weird, because I just tried the code and it works fine for me. Maybe it is some other part of the code that messes things up, so you might want to post a little more code.